# $x\in U$, $y\in U^c$. Some convex combination of $x,y$ must be on the boundary of $U$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$.

$x\in U$, $y\in U^c$

Some convex combination of $x,y$ must be on the boundary of $U$?

Seems very obvious and the proof is simple when $n=1$. I don't know how to apply this proof to higher dimensional cases.

Maybe I can still use the fact that the union of two disjoint open interval cannot be a connected open interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be generalized as follows:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $U \subset X$ be open, $x \in U$, $y \in X \setminus U$ and $f :  [0,1] \to X$ be continuous path such that $f(0) = x$ and $f(1) = y$. Then there exists $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t) \in \operatorname{bd} U$.

We have $\operatorname{bd} U = \overline U \setminus U$. The space $X$ is the disjoint union of $U, U'  = X \setminus \overline U$ and $\operatorname{bd} U$. The sets $U, U'$ are open, $\operatorname{bd} U$ is closed. Thus $[0,1]$ is the disjoint union of the open sets $V = f^{-1}(U), V' = f^{-1}(U')$ and the closed set $B = f^{-1}(\operatorname{bd} U)$. The set $V$ is non-empty ($x \in V$).

Assume that there does not exist $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(t) \in \operatorname{bd} U$. Then $B = \emptyset$. Thus $[0,1]$ is the disjoint union of the open sets $V$ and $V'$. Since $[0,1]$ is connected, one of these sets must be empty, and this set must be $V'$. Thus $y \notin V'$, i.e. $f(y) \notin U' =  X \setminus \overline U$ which means $f(y) \in \overline U$. Since $f(y) \notin U$, we see that $f(y) \in \operatorname{bd} U$ which contradicts $B = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the mapping $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(t) = (1-t)x + ty$.
First, the mapping $f(t)$ is continuous.
Thus, the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$.
Let $t_0 = \sup f^{-1}(U)$.

Since there exists a sequence $\{t_n\} \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ such that $t_n \to t_0$, we have that $f(t_n) \to f(t_0)$.
It follows that $f(t_0)$ is on the closure of $U$.

If $t_0 =1$, then $f(t_0)=y \not\in U$. If $t_0 < 1$, suppose that $f(t_0) \in U$ and then we have that $t_0 \in f^{-1}(U)$.
Note that the set $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. This contradicts with the maximality of $t_0$.
So, we conclude that $f(t_0) \not\in U$.

Therefore, we have that $f(t_0)=(1-t_0)x + t_0 y$ must be on the boundary of $U$.